# Not calling method from inherited class

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, tostring

In this instance I have 3 classes. Method class, Book class, AllBook class class.
AllBooks extends book class. Methods class is where most of my methods are (duh). I am having problems with only one namely the addBook method.

Code:

Method class

```
public class methods {
// Variables
int bCount = 0;
int mCount = 0;
int lCount = 0;
int boCount = 0;
//Arrays
Book[] bArr = new Book[500];
Member[] mArr = new Member[250];
Librarian[] lArr = new Librarian[50];
MainMenu mm;
public void newBook() {
    int cont2 = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
    int cont = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
    int choice = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
    while (choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        String ttl = mm.tiltleTF.getText();
        String athr = mm.authorTF.getText();
        String gnr = mm.genreTF.getText();
        String lctn = mm.locationTF.getText();
        String cndtn = mm.conditionTF.getText();
        if (athr == null && gnr == null && lctn == null && cndtn == null) {
            cont = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You have left out some fields are you sure you wish to continue?", "Information left out", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        }
        while (cont == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            ttl = ttl.toUpperCase();
            athr = athr.toUpperCase();
            gnr = gnr.toUpperCase();
            lctn = lctn.toUpperCase();
            cndtn = cndtn.toUpperCase();
            cont2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "The book you wish to enter is:" + "\n Title:\t" + ttl + "\n Author:\t" + athr + "\n Genre:/t" + gnr + "\n Location: \n" + lctn + "\n Condition:\t" + cndtn, "Are you sure?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            while (cont2 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                bArr[bCount] = new AllBooks(bCount, ttl, athr, gnr, "IN", lctn, cndtn);
                try {
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("books.txt", true));
                    pw.println(bArr[bCount].toString(0);
                    pw.close();
                    bCount++;
                    displayBooks();
                    choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Book added! Do you wish to enter another book?", "Enter another book?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Allbooks

```
public class AllBooks extends Book {

private String genre;
private String status;
private String Location;
private String condition;

public AllBooks(int bookID, String title, String author, String genre, String status, String Location, String condition) {
    super(bookID, title, author);
    this.genre = genre;
    this.status = status;
    this.Location = Location;
    this.condition = condition;
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return Location;
}

public void setLocation(String Location) {
    this.Location = Location;
}

public String getCondition() {
    return condition;
}

public void setCondition(String condition) {
    this.condition = condition;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String stg = "";
    stg = stg + getBookID() + '\t' + getTitle() + addSpaces(getTitle(), 30) + getAuthor() + addSpaces(getAuthor(), 30) + genre + addSpaces(genre, 15) + status + addSpaces(status, 5) + Location + addSpaces(Location, 20) + condition;
    return stg;
}

public String toString(int i) {
    String stg = "";
    stg += getBookID() + "#" + getTitle() + "#" + getAuthor() + "#" + getGenre() + "#" + getStatus() + "#" + getLocation() + "#" + getCondition() + "#";
    return stg;
}
```

}

Book
public class Book {

```
private int bookID;
private String title;
private String author;


public Book() {
}

public Book(int bookID, String title, String author) {
    this.bookID = bookID;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
}

public int getBookID() {
    return bookID;
}

public void setBookID(int bookID) {
    this.bookID = bookID;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}


public String addSpaces(String s, int w) {
    String spc = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= (w - s.length()); i++) {
        spc = spc + " ";
    }
    return spc;
}
```

}

The problem I am having is that in the newBook method when it is writing to the file with the toString, it not "linking(?)" or recognizing the toString (in i) method in the all books class. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Is your newBook method in the Book class?  Inheritance works such that things can only inherit from things that are *above* them, so if you want a method to be propagated down the inheritance tree you must define it at a *higher* level than the class that you want to use it in.

Aka. Define your toString method in Book, not in AllBooks.

Answer (score 0):

toString() does not expect any argument. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29

Answer (score 0):

You only define the toString(i) in your child class, not parent.
When you use the code to create new child object using code below

```
bArr[bCount] = new AllBooks(bCount, ttl, athr, gnr, "IN", lctn, cndtn);
```

The compiler could not identify which object is created, so only the methods defined in parent class could be linked. It will only konw the type your defined first, type is Book

```
Book[] bArr
```